# How can I get reasonably-priced APPLE-II manuals?

Tags: apple-ii

I am making a emulated apple-ii based on a raspberry pi and a custom chassis. I would like to have physical manuals to go along with it.

Obvious approaches are to download and print one of, or to pay exorbitant prices on eBay. Neither of those options is obviously good. (The first is poor quality, the second is pricey and uncertain quality).

Is there any reprint service or similar where I can get reasonably priced, decently durable reproduction manuals?

Alternate solutions are welcome too.

Comment: Were to buy questions are not really a fit for RC.SE

Comment: Reprint services need a good copy to work from too. I suggest buying original manuals - that way at least a part of your setup is real. Plenty of relatively cheap manuals are being sold on on eBay right now., eg. Apple II reference manual $34.99 https://www.ebay.com/itm/403262036794?epid=2131977023&hash=item5de44a5b3a:g:O6IAAOSwroRheqnx I bet that price is way cheaper than it was new!

Comment: @Raffzahn https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60610228#60610228

Comment: @fectin Random chat is not a valid source. Better check Meta instead. RC.SE does support questions to find sources for hard to gather items. Just, Apple II manuals are not rare. They have been printed in millions. More important, your question does fall even less into any acceptable sub category, as you show that you're well aware about sources to find them. Scanned and genuine. The added _'reasonable priced'_ is opinion, not fact. Thus the question boils down to a _'but I want it cheap'_ topic which is of no value to the site or future readers

Comment: There is a way to write this question so that it is appropriate. Don't ask where you can find the answer to the question, just ask the question, if that makes sense

Comment: This is not really a question related to retro computing as much as it is about the buying process.  Asking "Where?" would help some, because an answer can be provided that does have something to do with retrocomputing specifically.  Please do continue asking questions!  Early feed back does help.

Comment: stackexchange sites are generally meant for questions that have answers with some durability. Answers to the question as stated would involve a list of auction sites and reprint services operating today, which might not be at all useful a year from now. I don't think this question is a good fit for stackexchange.

Comment: @Raffzahn to be fair that’s not quite random chat, the question there was answered by one of the site’s moderators so it’s understandable that fectin would take it as authoritative. (I agree with the rest of your comment.)

Comment: @StephenKitt Well, holding an office doesn't make an opinion binding rule. More important, the answer is quite vague, given ahead of the posted question, thus not really relevant as an afterwards justification. Moreso, presenting it as link only it at least dubious. And last, but not least, and that's the point I made, some chat does not overrule meta.RC.SE or even less any basic SE rules.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you value your time, and the legal aspects, one approach could be to re-create the manuals and have them printed by a print service. (Recommendations of print services are not retrocomputing-related and thus off-topic here.)

This might seem crazy but [it has been done for the Commodore 64](https://pickledlight.blogspot.com/p/commodore-64-guides.html) and [for the BBC Micro](https://stardot.org.uk/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14024).